# Get movie information from IMDb API website

Tags: python, python-2.7

I used scrapy spiders to crawl the IMDb ID from the IMDb website already.
So now, I am going to use the IMDb API website & the IMDb ID I have collected to build a dictionary and save it into a json file.

```
import requests
import json


def query_url(id):


    #query_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i='+id+'&plot=short&r=json'
    return query_url


def get_movie_ids(input_file):
    #id_list= []
    #with open (input_file, 'r') as f:
        #for line in f:
            #id_list.append(line.strip())    # sth like ['tt0407887', 'tt1212123', ... ]
    return id_list


def get_all_data(in_file, out_file):
    movie_data_dict = {}
    movie_ids = get_movie_ids(in_file)

    id_counter = 0
    session = requests.Session()

    for id in movie_ids:
        url = query_url(id)

        #try:
            #movie_data = session.get(url).json() # to catch corrupted json file
        #except ValueError:
            #pass

        movie_data_dict[id_counter] = movie_data
        id_counter += 1

    with open(out_file, 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(movie_data_dict, f)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    movie_id_file = r'../IMDbIDCrawler/movie_id10-15' # the IMDb ID crawled by Scrapy
    movie_data_file = 'IMDb2010-2015.json'
    get_all_data(movie_id_file, movie_data_file)
```

When i run the code in command prompt, the code simply wouldn't run.
I dont know what I have done wrong in the above script..

This is a Python homework. So the codes marked by # is written by me while the other codes are provided in the first place. SO this is the thing......the pace of the course is very very fast and I can't catch up the course.And I have no one to ask to. So, please forgive me if I asked some really stupid / beginner questions...........

Comment: Do you have error message ?

Comment: when running in command prompt? No error message.It just won't run :(

Comment: but when i run the code in python, it did show  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../IMDbIDCrawler/movie_id10-15'  but im pretty sure i have this file in my laptop??

Comment: is `movie_id_file` variable the absolute path to your file ?

Comment: Does my last comment answered your question ?

Comment: does `command prompt` mean bash/terminal/console/cmd.exe/powershell ? Did you try without line `if __name__ == '__main__':` ? Did you try absolute path ? Python sometimes may run in different folder than you expect and relative path may not work.